# Camera shake on collision in unity 3d

Tags: c#, camera, unity-game-engine

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/212189/camera-shake.html 
I've followed the question's answer above to try and get a camera shake working for my first person camera. But I've tried to modify it so that the camera shakes from an invisible collision box.

So far my camera shake script looks like this;

```
public bool Shaking; 
private float ShakeDecay;
private float ShakeIntensity;   
private Vector3 OriginalPos;
private Quaternion OriginalRot;

void Start()
{
Shaking = false;   
}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collision)
{
if(collision.gameObject.name == "ShakeTrigger")
{
    DoShake();  
    Debug.Log("The camera trigger has hit");
}
}


void Update () 
{
if(ShakeIntensity > 0)
{
    transform.position = OriginalPos + Random.insideUnitSphere * ShakeIntensity;
    transform.rotation = new Quaternion(OriginalRot.x + Random.Range(-ShakeIntensity, ShakeIntensity)*.2f,
                              OriginalRot.y + Random.Range(-ShakeIntensity, ShakeIntensity)*.2f,
                              OriginalRot.z + Random.Range(-ShakeIntensity, ShakeIntensity)*.2f,
                              OriginalRot.w + Random.Range(-ShakeIntensity,     ShakeIntensity)*.2f);

   ShakeIntensity -= ShakeDecay;
}
else if (Shaking)
{
   Shaking = false;  
}

}


void OnGUI() {

 if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 200, 50, 30), "Shake"))
   DoShake();
   //Debug.Log("Shake");

}     

public void DoShake()
{
OriginalPos = transform.position;
OriginalRot = transform.rotation;

ShakeIntensity = 0.3f;
ShakeDecay = 0.02f;
Shaking = true;
}
```

I know the code works 100% via the gui button. This script is attached to the camera on the first person controller. An invisible collision box with the tag ShakeTrigger is in the game. However, the debug log doesn't get called at all and I'm unsure why.

If anyone needs any more information just let me know.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Does the "invisible" box collider have `Is Trigger` checked?  If not, OnTriggerEnter will never be called.  Also make sure camera is attached to a rigid body collider.  [Here is a good link](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/class-MeshCollider.html) for Unity's collision matrix.

Comment: The collision box does have 'is trigger' checked. I already have some sound in a separate script attached to the same box which works fine. The camera that has this script is the "main camera" which is attached to the first person controller (which I'm guessing already has the rigidbody). Still not got this method to work properly :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the script is attached to your camera, then OnTriggerEnter is looking at the camera for a trigger call, not the collision box.

One thing you could do is stick the OnTriggerEnter into a new script and put that inside the collision box. Then have that do a SendMessage along these lines:

`GameObject.Find("Camera").SendMessage("DoShake");`

EDIT: To answer Jerdak's questions.

The code bellow would be within the TriggerBox:

```
void Start()
{
    ...   
}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collision)
{
    if(collision.gameObject.name == "ShakeTrigger")
{
    GameObject.Find("Camera").SendMessage("DoShake");  
    Debug.Log("The camera trigger has hit");
}
}...
```

and this would be within the Camera:

```
void Start()
{
    ...  
}

public void DoShake()
{
    OriginalPos = transform.position;
    OriginalRot = transform.rotation;

    ShakeIntensity = 0.3f;
    ShakeDecay = 0.02f;
    Shaking = true;
}...
```

This way, triggerbox is responsible for detecting triggers and only ever sends a message to the camera when right kind of object goes through it. The camera is then responsible for doing the shaking.

Comment: This code works great but it causes a glitch. Once I walk into the trigger box it makes the camera shake but it moves the camera behind the first person controller :L. Yet the "shake" button on the GUI calls the same method (DoShake) and doesn't cause the same problem.

Comment: Just got it to work. I had changed the "Camera" quote to "Main Camera" (which is what its called on the first person controller). Without realizing that this should have been "Player" instead. I have read that the SendMessage function can be bad for performance but I'll use it for now! Thanks alot for your help :D

Comment: This is generally a bad idea.  **Any** rigid body or character controller entering that trigger will cause the camera to shake.  It's also really unclear why you're doing a global find when gameobject is passed in as an argument: collision.gameObject.

Comment: @Jerdak Maybe I didn't phrase it clearly... If he sticks the onTriggerEnter method 'as is' into a new script, and simply replaces `DoShake()` with my line of code, then the shake will still only trigger when needed. `GameObject.Find(..)` is there to find the Camera object (not the object colliding with the triggerbox) because the `DoShake()` method is within the camera's script.

Comment: @StevenMills Any object w/ a rigidbody passing through that trigger will send OnShake() to the camera.  Maybe that's the OPs intent, it isn't clear.  But since the OP wanted to trigger a shake when the camera was passing through the trigger, it stands to reason the camera is the catalyst.  In your setup, any enemy NPC randomly running through the trigger would cause OnShake().

Comment: @Jerdak I've edited the main post to make it clearer how this works. Hope this explains my point better.

Answer (score 1):

To shake your camera on the collision or Trigger you need to first Make function of Your Shake that you can also call from other scripts

Something like

```
public class ShakeCamera : MonoBehavior
{
    public bool canShake;
    
    private void Update()
    {
       if(canShake)
       DoShake()
    }
    public void DoShake()
    {
        // Shake Logic
    }
    public void StartShake()
    {
       canShake = true;
    }
    public void StopShake()
    {
       canShake = false;
    }
}
```

And from your other script whenever you trigger the target object you can call it like this

```
    public class TriggerScript: MonoBehavior
        {
            public ShakeCamera shakeCamera;

            private void Start()
            {
                shakeCamera = FindObjectOfType<ShakeCamera>();
            }

            void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collision)
            {
                 if(collision.gameObject.tag == "targetTag")// Change Tag accroding to your requirement
                    {
                      
                        cameraShake.StartShake();
                    } 
             }
            void OnTriggerExit(Collider collision)
            {
                 if(collision.gameObject.tag == "targetTag")// Change Tag accroding to your requirement
                    {
                        cameraShake.StopShake();
                    } 
             }
        }
```

I am attaching one reference video for you, May be it would help you in better camera shake. Hope it was helpful.

You can refer to this video I made https://youtu.be/9X_JXexwfR4

Comment: When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.

Answer (score -1):

If you have set up rigidbody then change the interpolate from none to interpolate.